# Appending _?NumericQ automatically to every variable of a function in the definition

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

I have a list of expressions as follows:

```
as=Table[a[k],{k,1,500}]
```

I would like to append `_?NumericQ` to every element of this list and the result should look like this

```
{a[1]_?NumericQ,a[2]_?NumericQ,...,a[500]_?NumericQ}
```

Then I would like to transform this thing to

{a1_?NumericQ,a2_?NumericQ,...,a500_?NumericQ}

For this I need to be able to transform

```
as={a[1],...,a[500]}
```

to

```
bs={a1,...,a500}
```

This is needed when one needs to define functions with alot of variables such that hand typing them is not fiesable and symbolic computations are not desired.

Actually I only want to define a function with many variables as

```
obj[a1_?NumericQ,a2_?NumericQ,...,a500_?NumericQ]
```

That question is different than mine: there one has to type the variable still by hand.. I am looking for everything automized not only for $5$ elements.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform maybe nothing but it doesnt solve my problem. Normally we use _?NumericQ to speed up the process just with numerical computations. If I have $500$ variables, say $a1,...,a500$, I have an objective function ``obj[a1_?NumericQ,a2_?NumericQ........]`` I want to defined this without writing $500$ terms over there... Is it possible to let the mathematica do this for me?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Definitely check out the link in @MichaelE2's comment -- [Szabolcs's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/68867/6358) should be a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
With[{
 lhs = ReplacePart[
  Table[
   PatternTest[
    Pattern[Evaluate[Symbol["a" <> IntegerString[k]]], Blank[]], 
    NumericQ
    ],
   {k, 1, 500}
   ],
  0 -> obj
  ],
 rhs = 1
 },
SetDelayed[lhs, rhs]
]
```

The list of variables can be obtained with

```
Table[Symbol["a" <> IntegerString[k]], {k, 1, 500}]
```

But on the long run, a better strategy might be to define your function like so:

```
obj[a_?(VectorQ[#,NumericQ]&)] := ...
```

and to refer to the entries of `a` with `Indexed[a,i]` on the right hand side. (And yes, functions like `FindMinimum` and `FindRoot` can be convinced to work such functions.)

Comment: that seems great. I need to know two more things. 1. I need to get rid of the brackets of a list, because with the brackets ``obj[{}]:=``definition does not work. 2. I also need the list {a1,a2,...,a500}.

Comment: why is toexpression dangerous? the second one has ``:`` additionally.

Comment: With `ToExpression` there is the possibility that some string with harmfull code can be injected. Notice that Mathematica has write access to your local files. For superfluous `:`, please see my edit.

Comment: what is this code doing? It does not give any output. What is lhs and rhs btw? how to delete the brackets $\{$ and $\}$?

Comment: This code defines your desired function `obj`. Check out `??obj`. `lhs` is the pattern for which the rule is defined (the "function"), `rhs` is the expression that is supposed to be evaluated when the function is called. Here, I put `rhs = 1`.

Comment: Thank you once again.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to name your variables, but don't want to repeat the pattern test `?NumericQ` for each variable, you can use [`PatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternSequence):

```
f[PatternSequence[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_]?NumericQ] := {a1, a1+a4, a2+a3, a5}
```

Check:

```
f[1,2,3,4,5]
f[1,2,a,4,5]
```

> {1, 5, 5, 5}
>
> f[1, 2, a, 4, 5]

Answer (score 4):

> Actually I only want to define a function with many variables as
>
> `obj[a1_?NumericQ,a2_?NumericQ,...,a500_?NumericQ]`

In this case I think it would be much simpler to use something like

```
obj[vars__?NumericQ /; Length[{vars}] === 5] := Module[
    {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5},
    {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5} = {vars};
    (* do something useful here, like *)
    Total @ {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}
]
```

Now `obj` behave exactly as you want, but you don't have to do any voodoo with creating your definition.

```
In[11]:= obj[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Out[11]= 15

In[12]:= obj[1, 2, 3, a + 4, 5]

Out[12]= obj[1, 2, 3, 4 + a, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what the OP "only wants" at the end of the question, there's this:

```
vs = ToExpression[
   Table["a" <> ToString[i], {i, 500}],
   StandardForm, 
   Function[v, v_?NumericQ, HoldAll]];

ClearAll[obj];
Evaluate[obj @@ vs] := a3 + 4 a450; (* substitute function body *)

obj @@ Range[500]
(*  1803  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[Array[With[{v = Symbol["a"<>ToString[#]]}, v_?NumericQ] &, 7, 1, Sequence]] := {a1, a5}

f @@ Range[7]
```

> {1, 5}

```
f @@ (Log @ Range @ 7)
```

> {0, Log[5]}

```
f @@ Range[5]
```

> f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

```
f[foo, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

> f[foo, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]